# How to make icons appear at top of MacVim again

Tags: macvim

I just upgraded to a new version of MacVim.

There used to be a row of icons at the top of every MacVim window with buttons for opening/saving files, cut/paste/delete, etc. Now that row of buttons is gone.

What is that row of buttons called and how do I get it to appear again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the editor--

```
:set guioptions+=T
```

you can embed this command in $USER/.gvimrc to make sure it happens every time you start up.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to toggle the toolbar temporarily, you can also use the GUI:

[image]

Comment: I chose the setting ":set guioptions+=T" as the accepted answer but this answer is also quite helpful. Thanks.